# Want to display "True" and "False" buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a grid of buttons where user opens up the gird by clicking on the (Open Grid) link and then clicking on a button in that grid. What I want to do is that if user clicks on the "True or False" button, then it should output buttons "True" and "False" underneath the "Number of Answers" textbox. But it is not displaying anything. What am I doing wrong?

The code is here:

```
$(".gridBtns").click(function() {

   var clickedNumber = this.value;

   $('.answerBtns').each(function (index) {
      if (index < clickedNumber)
         $(this).show();
      else
         $(this).hide();
   });

   if (document.getElementsByClassName("gridBtns").value == "True or False")
   {
       document.getElementId("answerTrue").style.display = "block";
   }

});
```

Full code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSy97/16/)

Comment: FWIW `getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE8 and below... but why don't you use jQuery in that case?

Comment: you are comparing in different statement in different place for same element 1) $(".gridBtns").click   2) document.getElementsByClassName("gridBtns").value  i am not sure what is happening

Comment: Interestingly, `querySelector('.classname')` does work in IE8, so is a better choice than `getElementsByClassName` in that regard.

Comment: Thanks everybody attempting to answer my question, greatly appreciate it. I have found an answer so this question is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("gridBtns").value == "True or False")
{
    document.getElementId("answerTrue").style.display = "block";
}
```

Try this:

```
if (this.id=='btnTrueorFalse') {
    $('#answerTrue').show();
    $('#answerFalse').show();
}
```

Besides the 1/many error already mentioned in another post, it looks like the original is just looking for the wrong property in the wrong place.

Comment: Great.  Also, you can simplify the hide/show loop.  Replace the entire loop with:


    $('.answerBtns').hide();
    $('.answerBtns:lt(' + clickedNumber + ')').show();

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList (which acts like an array), not a single Element.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code to equal your code above would be

```
if($('.gridBtns').val() == 'True or False'){
  $('#answerTrue').show(); //you may also use .css() for it, but show() has the same    result
}
```

Comment: Hi, thannks for the conversion into jquery but it does display the "True" or "Flase" button underneath when I select the "True or False" button from the grid. I have edit the jsfiddle to include the code you have game me. Don't know why it is not appearing

Comment: Because that's what `display:block` (show() doesn't make anything else) does. So do it via css with `$('anserTrue').css('display','inline'); instead

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing this code here for a while now:

If you use jQuery, **use** it. Doing document.getElementById(..) suddenly is just nonsensical. Just use jQuery selectors everywhere, and methods (f.i. .addClass(..) instead of .className = ..). jQuery is the way you access your DOM, using a mix is just confusing.

Also, I notice most of your problems with this Ui stem from the fact that:

- It is a bad UI (no offense, just think about it)
- You use the UI for storing state. Don't do that. UI should be dependent on state, not the other way around.

Comment: Yeah my problem is I do not know many jquery functions so I tend to use more javascript programming if you know what I mean. But somebody showed me the jquery equivalent so I can use that so my code isn't mixed up with Jquery and getElements

Comment: Sorry, this answer is nothing but impractical dreck. Sizzle is a horribly inefficient garbage pile. Use `document.getElementById` over `$("#whatever")` whenever possible. There's a big speed difference, believe it or not.

Comment: ?? The amount of downvotes is confusing me: the author clearly needs jQuery selectors. I truly believe and know the performance differences but this has no matter here. Your advice just has an adverse effect on what you're trying to communicate.